# How to load a DLL file from a specific URL in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, webclient, .net-assembly

I would like to download a DLL file from http://localhost:8080/bin/ and instantiate classes and functions in my Asp.Net Core application.

I've made a little console application (in .NET Framwork) doing this. Here the code  :

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                var myDll = Assembly.Load(wc.DownloadData("http://localhost:8080/test-dll/bin/myDll.dll"));

                Type t = myDll .GetType("ConsoleApplication1.Test");


                // Instantiate my class

                object myObject = new object();
                myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, WebClient is not supported in .Net Core.

So, how can I load a dll file located in a specific URL and instantiate it ? (in .Net Core)

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to download file in ASP.Net core using following code.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:55272/myDll.dll";
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                using (var inputStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    var mydll = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(inputStream);

                }
            }
        }
```

But remember that certain file types such as .config, .dll .exe are protected in IIS and you will not be able to download such files with default settings/configuration of IIS. You need to configure that part explicitly. May be this [link](https://blogs.infosupport.com/getting-iis-to-serve-any-file-type/) can be helpful on that front.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace ConslApp
{
    class Prog
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var web = new Web())
            {
                var myDll = Assembly.Load(web.DownloadData("http://localhost:8080/test-dll/bin/myDll.dll"));

                Type t = myDll .GetType("ConslApp.Test");


               // Instantiate my class

               object Obj = new object();
               obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is Web() ? Where does it come from ?